# Waiting for child process in other terminal works if launched with 'x-terminal-emulator' but not if launched with 'gnome-terminal'

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal, xterm, konsole

My ultimate goal is to let my python script launch a child process, in *another* terminal, that runs independently from the parent:

- When the parent process finishes, the child process should continue. It should not be killed.
- The parent process should be able to either wait for the child to finish, or just continue its own stuff.

I achieved the goal with the script below. Please note that the child process I chose to launch is `python3 child.py`, but it can be anything else (and doesn't have to be a python process). Also note that, in this case, I let the parent process wait for the child process by adding the `.communicate()` in the end.

```py
# Script parent.py
# ================
import subprocess, shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Launch child process')
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['x-terminal-emulator', '-e', 'python3', 'child.py'],
    ).communicate()
    print('Child process finished')
    exit(0)
```

I then launch the parent:

```bash
$ python3 parent.py
```

It works great. The parent first prints `'Launch child process'`, then the child process appears *in another terminal*. The child does its things, then closes. *After the child closes*, the parent prints `'Child process finished'`. Great!

Unfortunately, The `x-terminal-emulator` is only present on Debian and derivatives. My goal is to make this approach work on *most* Linux systems.

The most sensible approach I could find so far, would be to try out a few default 'terminal emulators' that are present on the most common Linux distros. For example:

- `'gnome-terminal'`
- `'konsole'`
- `'xterm'`
- `'urxvt'`
- `'rxvt'`
- `'termit'`
- `'terminator'`
- `$TERMINAL` (this is a non-standard variable)

I tried with `'gnome-terminal'` to get started, but it already goes wrong:

```py
# Script parent.py
# ================
import subprocess, shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Launch child process')
    # For the 'gnome-terminal', the '-e' argument is deprecated.
    # One should use the '--' argument instead.
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['gnome-terminal', '--', 'python3', 'child.py'],
    ).communicate()
    print('Child process finished')
    exit(0)
```

The child process launches, but the parent doesn't wait for it to finish - even though I instructed it explicitely to do so by adding the `.communicate()` at the end of `Popen(..)`.

In other words, the parent prints `'Child process finished'` immediately, before the child has actually finished.

---

**Question 1:**
Why is this approach working for `'x-terminal-emulator'` and not for `'gnome-terminal'`? PS: I'm working on Ubuntu.

*EDIT: I found the solution to this problem. One has to add the `--wait` flag to tell the `gnome-terminal` not to return until its child process exits.*

**Question 2:**
How can I get this approach working on *most* Linux systems? If I try to launch any other terminal emulator like `xterm`, `konsole`, ... should I expect similar problems? I can't test right now, because I only have Ubuntu for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have a reasonably good approach now. I list the most common terminal emulators in Linux, and loop over them to see which one is present on the system. Then I launch the child process in that terminal.

There are a few subtle differences between the terminals. I've installed some on my Ubuntu to figure out. This is what I have so far:

```py
# parent.py
# =========
import sys, subprocess, shutil, shlex
from typing import *

def __get_terminal() -> Tuple[str, str]:
    '''
    Find a terminal present on this system. Return it as a tuple (terminal_name, terminal_path).
    For example: ('gnome-terminal', '/usr/bin/gnome-terminal').
    '''
    terminal_list = [
        'gnome-terminal', 'x-terminal-emulator', 'xterm', 'konsole', 'xfce4-terminal', 'qterminal',
        'lxterminal', 'alacritty', 'terminator',
    ]
    terminal_name = None
    terminal_path = None
    for terminal in terminal_list:
        if shutil.which(terminal):
            terminal_name = terminal
            terminal_path = shutil.which(terminal)
            break
        continue
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('No terminal found!')
    return terminal_name, terminal_path


def __launch_in_terminal(program:str, argv:List[str]) -> None:
    '''
    Launch the given program in a terminal and pass it the arguments in argv.
    '''
    terminal_name, terminal_path = __get_terminal()
    print(f'terminal_name = {terminal_name}')
    print(f'terminal_path = {terminal_path}')
    print(f'__launch_in_terminal({program}, {argv})')

    # The 'gnome-terminal' requires a '--wait' argument to let it not return until its child process
    # has completed. Also, this terminal needs the '--' argument instead of '-e', which is depre-
    # cated.
    if terminal_name == 'gnome-terminal':
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            [terminal_path, '--wait', '--', program, *argv],
        )
        p.wait()

    # The 'xfce4-terminal' and 'terminator' terminal emulators don't work if you pass the program
    # and arguments as separate list elements. So you need to join them with shlex.
    elif terminal_name in ('xfce4-terminal', 'terminator'):
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            [terminal_path, '-e', shlex.join([program, *argv])],
        )
        p.wait()

    # For all other terminal emulators, the approach is the same.
    else:
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            [terminal_path, '-e', program, *argv],
        )
        p.wait()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Launch child process')
    # Launch the child process in another terminal, and pass it the arguments that were given to
    # this parent process. To make a demonstration, we choose the child process to be a python
    # interpreter running the 'child.py' script.
    __launch_in_terminal(
        program = 'python3',
        argv    = ['child.py', *sys.argv[1:]],
    )
    print('Child process finished')
    exit(0)
```

Please let me know if I forgot one of the "big" ones, or if I made any mistakes in launching some of these terminals.

---

If you want to test this script, just copy-paste it into a `parent.py` file. You'll also need a `child.py` file in the same folder. That `child.py` file can be anything. Feel free to take this sample code:

```py
# child.py
# ========
from typing import *
import sys, os, time, argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Start child process')
    print('===================')
    input('Press any key to continue...')
    print('')

    # Is this frozen?
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('Frozen:'.ljust(20), end='')
    print(getattr(sys, "frozen", False))

    # Print the executable running this script. It will be the Python interpreter in general, or
    # the frozen executable if running from compiled code.
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('sys.executable:'.ljust(20), end='')
    print(sys.executable.replace('\\', '/'))

    # Print the value of __file__
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('__file__:'.ljust(20), end='')
    print(__file__.replace('\\', '/'))

    # Print the location of this file. It should be equal to __file__ if the Python interpreter is
    # running this script. If this is running as compiled code, the location of this file differs
    # from the value of __file__.
    file_location:Optional[str] = None
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # Frozen, running as compiled code
        file_location = os.path.realpath(sys.executable).replace('\\', '/')
    else:
        # Running from interpreter
        file_location = os.path.realpath(__file__).replace('\\', '/')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('File location:'.ljust(20), end='')
    print(file_location)

    # Print the arguments given to this program
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Simple program', add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo',  action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar',  action='store')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print('Arguments:')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(f'    --help = {args.help}')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(f'    --foo  = {args.foo}')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(f'    --bar  = {args.bar}')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(f'    sys.argv = {sys.argv}')

    # Exit
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print('')
    input('Press any key to continue...')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Then run the parent like so:

```bash
$ python3 parent.py --foo --bar=baz
```